# Why is this LSM303d register address being used with an OR and an address operator?

Tags: stm32, i2c, arm, programming

I'm trying to get the data of a LSM303d accelerometer using anSTM32 via the I2C bus.

I've found online that to get the data from the OUT_X_L_A register (low byte of x component of the accelerometer) you need to use HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Transmit and Receive. I didn't really know how to use it so I searched for some code example online and [I've found exactly what I was searching for](https://github.com/z49x2vmq/lsm303/blob/master/lsm303dlhc.c) on a github repo.

Even if the code seems right in one of the functions he is using the register address with an OR operator and I can't figure out why.

```
void lsm303dlhc_read_la(I2C_HandleTypeDef *i2c, uint8_t *buf) {
    uint8_t reg = OUT_X_L_A | 0b10000000;

    HAL_StatusTypeDef ret;

    ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Transmit_IT(i2c, LA_ADDRESS, &reg, 1, I2C_FIRST_FRAME);
    if (ret != HAL_OK) {
        return;
    }

    while (!__HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(i2c, I2C_FLAG_TC));

    ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Receive_IT(i2c, LA_ADDRESS, buf, 6, I2C_LAST_FRAME);
    if (ret != HAL_OK) {
        return;
    }
    while(i2c->State != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY);
}
```

Why is he writing:

```
uint8_t reg = OUT_X_L_A | 0b10000000;
ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Transmit_IT(i2c, LA_ADDRESS, &reg, 1, I2C_FIRST_FRAME);
```

instead of:

```
uint8_t reg = OUT_X_L_A;
ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Transmit_IT(i2c, LA_ADDRESS, reg, 1, I2C_FIRST_FRAME);
```

Please note that OUT_X_L_A is defined in lsm303dlhc.h and its value is 0x28 according to the register address in the [datasheet.](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J703/LSM303D.pdf)

The value of OUT_X_L_A | 0b10000000 is 0xa8(not a valid register address according to the datasheet) so the & operator must do something I don't know of in this context otherwise this won't work.

Comment: What number is 0b10000000 ?

Comment: What do you mean the signification or the value ? In decimal? In Hex? It's 128 in decimal and 0x80 (or 80h) in hex

Comment: Could it be a kind of Start signal for the handshake?

Comment: it could be I will investigate further but I don't find something that look like 0b10000000 in the datasheet (especially under the i2c operations)

Comment: The value in question is being passed as one of the arguments in a call to the software routine named `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()`.  Perhaps the set/clear state of the 8th bit of that argument acts as a flag to that routine?

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 6.6.1 of the datasheet explains the auto increment function of this bit:

> After the START condition (ST) a slave address is sent, once a slave
> acknowledge (SAK) has been returned, an 8-bit sub-address is transmitted: the 7 LSb
> represent the actual register address while the MSb enables address auto-increment. If the
> MSb of the SUB field is 1, the SUB (register address) is automatically incremented to allow
> multiple data read/write.